# Dynamic Context Menu XAML where items are located into an observablecollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am creating an App where I have a map on a WPF where user can select points by double clicking on it (done and works!); however, I also want that when user right-clicks on it, a contextMenu (or somtething similar) will open and show the Names of the Markers (Marker is a defined class of the points selected by the user on the map with Latitude, Longitude & Name atributes).

This is the main idea, for doing that I have created an observable collection of Markers class but I am unable to bind it to the ContextMenu. So, I want that when user right clicks on the map, the menu will show all the names of the Markers and when user clicks on them, some method will be used.

How can I bind all these dynamic items and prepare the code to be able to create the methods for all the items shown when clicked? User can select at any time more markers so it should update.

Thanks in advance, I am stuck in this for weeks.

Here, it is shown the code:

**MapMarker class:**

```
{     class MapMarker 
    {
    public string Name { get;set;} // Marker name
    public double Latitude { get; set;} // Latitude coordinate
    public double Longitude { get; set; } // Longitude coordinate
    public int Posicio { get; set; } // Mapmarker location inside the list of pushpins
    public Image Icona { get; set; } // Mapmarker icon
    public string Comanda { get; set; } // Command when clicked
    } 
}
```

**Observable collection class:**

```
class OCollMapMarker : ObservableCollection<MapMarker>
{
    public MapMarker Mmarker { get; set; }
}
```

**Code behind .cs: (Fullfilling the observable collection)**

```
                MapMarker mpker= new MapMarker();
                mpker.Name = nameppin;
                mpker.Posicio = poslist;
                mpker.Latitude = valuep.Location.Latitude;
                mpker.Longitude = valuep.Location.Longitude;
                mpker.Icona = iconap;
                mpker.Comanda = comanpin;

                PushpCollect.Add(mpker);
```

**XAML: (Here is where I should bind but I have tried multiple thinks and not work)**

```
<WPF:Map.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu Name="Rclik" #####BINDHERE#####>
                <ContextMenu.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
                        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="False"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    </Style>
                </ContextMenu.Style>
```

Comment: You can bind the ItemsSource property to any IEnumerable: <ContextMenu Name="Rclik" ItemsSource="{Binding PushpCollect}">

Comment: @mm8 I have tried now but it does nothing; In fact, no contextmenu is displayed on the map. Thanks 2

Comment: Do you have a view model class or what is the DataContext of the map control?

Comment: @mm8 I have not defined them. What would be helpful?

Comment: How do you set the `DataContext` of the `Window` then? Unless this is a `UserControl` with a map on it then you don't really have to. You can leave all this in the code behind. And set the `DataContext = this;`.

Comment: @XAMlMAX I have tried now to define the Datacontext as you said in the code-behind but I think I am not doing it welll. Please, how can I do that properly? Thanks and sorry, I am currently learning this language

Comment: Don't worry, we are here to help. If this is a `UserControl` that is displaying a map then code behind is fine if you are reusing it. But if this is a `Window` or a part of it then you need to have a `ViewModel` to have `Binding` working and comply to the `MvvM` pattern. Are you using `MvvM`?

Comment: @XAMlMAX I have not been using it but I will try it now. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @mm8 Thanks for your help, I will try it now and tell you how is it going

Comment: @mm8 Hi! I am currently working, and I must do this in my free time. Let me spend 1-2 days and I will update. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If `PushpCollect` is a *public property* (but not field) that is defined in the code-behind of the window you should be able to bind to it like this:

```
<ContextMenu Name="Rclik" ItemsSource="{Binding PushpCollect, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">
    <ContextMenu.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Style>
    </ContextMenu.Style>
    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
        </Style>
    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
</ContextMenu>
```

But please always provide a full reproducible sample when asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve